# When travelling to New Zealand will Security know about my overstaying in US 19 years ago?

Tags: airport-security, overstaying, new-zealand

I overstayed a tourist visa to US from 1988 to 1997, was not caught, and went back to my native country. I wasn't deported, nor detained, nor removed, it was my decision to leave the country.

I don't need a visa to go to New Zealand (visa waiver country) but if I ever go there, will they find out at the Security check in the airport?

Answer (score 2):

New Zealand and USA exchange security [information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes) but naturally do not fully disclose how much. There is certainly the *possibility* Customs and Immigration in New Zealand will be able to look up your past. However that it was a long time ago and that you left voluntarily should at least count a little in your favour.